# HttpWebRequest client authentication

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate

I need to post some xmls to a https site with client certificate authentication, but couldn't do it successfully.

I have 2 .pem file supplied from provider like below: (I can't send all the data so cutted)

cert.pem:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC0DCCAjmgAwIBAgIKAd8CIHEBAwIEpjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBmTELMAkG

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

key.pem:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICWwIBAAKBgQC+HN6jHJD1zoGLHYj1ycvg1yajll5zb3gExoWv7k+RbXLGuDEX

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

What I was try to do is

```
private static string HttpRequest(string url, string data)
        {
            HttpWebRequest rq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);


            //string privateKey = File.ReadAllText("c:\\key.pem");

            //privateKey = privateKey.Replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            //privateKey = privateKey.Replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            //privateKey = privateKey.Replace("\n", "");

            //Byte[] byteArr = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);

            //How do I use below .pem files here to authentica
            rq.ClientCertificates.Add(clientcert);
            rq.Method = "POST";
            rq.Proxy = null;
            rq.ContentType = "application/www-form-urlencoded";

            string dataToSend = data;

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSend);
            rq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            string responseFromServer = null;

            try
            {
                Stream dataStream = rq.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();

                WebResponse _WebResponse = rq.GetResponse();
                dataStream = _WebResponse.GetResponseStream();

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {


            }

            return responseFromServer;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert your private key and pem certificate into #pkcs12 form:

`openssl pkcs12 -inkey private.key -in client_certificate.pem -export -out client_certificate.p12`

After this, you can specify this p12 file in your C# code:

`rq.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("c:\\client_certificate.p12"));`

Answer (score 0):

You need sent you certificate (public key) to the server by adding it to the request. Server uses the private key to validate request as far as I know.

Try to simply load you public key file if not working you need to convert it to ASN.1 DER format.

```
rq.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("c:\\cert.pem"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. When I looked to the System.New trace logs It tries to find the cert.pem private key then failed to find it, so throws exception